# Carregar uma url quando clicar em play do player

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Olá,

Estou tentando carregar uma url (abrir um link) quando clico em play de um player que é um plugin do Wordpress (WonderPlugin Audio Player). 
Imagino que possa ser feito isso em javascript, mas não sei como fazer.
O player tem classe definida para o play.
Além de tocar o audio que está no player também deveria abrir uma url.
Alguém pode ajudar?
Obrigada

Comment: Vc diz tipo se o cara clica no btn do play além de dar play no vídeo abra uma outra aba no navegar com outra página é isso?

Comment: Exatamente, não vai abrir outra aba, vai carregar um url que direciona para uma tab da mesma pagina, mas a idéia é essa, além de dar play também carregar essa url.

Comment: Então quando clicar no Play, vai aparecer um link na tela que quando a pessoa clica vai rolar para um outro lugar dentro da própria página?

Comment: Não, quando clicar no Play irá aparecer um lugar da pagina (o qual ja tenho url) e executar o Play ao mesmo tempo. Não aparece o link

Comment: Ana reformulei minha resposta, veja se agora está mais próximo do que vc precisa.